# Android RecyclerView backed by list that is constantly changing in size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which displays a `List` of paginated elements. 
Initially the size of the list will be `n`, but as you approach the top, more elements need to be loaded, and the adapter will fetch `p` elements ( and the list will grow to a size of `n + p`)

The way I am doing this is fetch `p` elements and prepend it to the list inside `onBindViewHolder` if `position` is 0:

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
    val elements: List<Any> = emptyList()

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //viewholder binding code
        if (position == 0) {
            loadPreviousPage()
        } 
    }

    private fun loadPreviousPage() {
        val newElements = someCall() //List of size p
        elements.addAll(0, newElements)
    }
}
```

This works fine for the most part. Here's the problem:

Suppose there are `3p` total elements (3 pages) that can be fetched, meaning the adapter starts off with `0` elements, then `loadPreviousPage` is called, and `elements` grows to `p`, `2p` and finally `3p`. What I'm seeing is that the list is getting updated, but the `View`s aren't.

Example:

If `p = 3`, my `elements`, per pagination call, looks like:

```
I   : g h i
II  : d e f g h i
III : a b c d e f g h i
```

But in my `RecyclerView`, I see something like `i d e d e f g h i`

If I scroll so that the incorrect `View`s go out of the screen and scroll back, everything is fine and the `RecyclerView` looks as expected (`a b c d e f g h i`)

I am not sure exactly what is happening, but this behaviour (and even state of the `RecyclerView`) is consistent and reproducible. I suspect that since the list size is changing, an element that used to be in position `m` is no longer at the same position after adding `p` elements to it, and the `RecyclerView` has not been notified of this. However, I cannot call `notiyItemChanged` in `loadPreviousPage` because it is being called from `onBindViewHolder`, at the time of layout itself.

How can I solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is modifying the data structure that backs the adapter without  notifying the adapter that its data set has been modified:

```
private fun loadPreviousPage() {
    val newElements = someCall() //List of size p
    elements.addAll(0, newElements)
}
```

As you said, you can't call any of the various `notifyDataSetChanged()` and related methods since you'd get:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
> ```

In my opinion, the correct way to handle this would be to delay the call to `loadPreviousPage()`, using `Handler.post()`. This gets you outside of the illegal window for calling the `notifyXyz` methods, but will keep you on the main thread so that you can call `notifyXyz`.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (position == 0) {
        Handler().post { loadPreviousPage() }
    } 
}

private fun loadPreviousPage() {
    val newElements = someCall() //List of size p
    elements.addAll(0, newElements)
    notifyItemRangeInserted(0, newElements.size);
}
```

Once `loadPreviousPage()` is invoked on a different thread, you're free to use the `notifyXyz` methods.

PS: it seems like just doing this in the bind call would instantly load all available pages. Once you "insert" a new page, that view holder will be bound again, which seems like it would trigger another page load. Maybe you've already solved this, but I wanted to call it out. However, it seemed outside the scope of your question, so I haven't addressed it here.

Comment: First, you are right that all pages are being loaded instantly. I did not know that the  `ViewHolder` is bound immediately, and thought it is bound on-demand. How can I get a hook into when an item is being rendered?

Also, the `Handler` solution doesn't seem to be working as expected (some elements in the view are still repeating/jumbled). Perhaps it's because all pages are being loaded immediately? `loadPreviousPage` is synchronized though.